# What is the maximum number of shards MongoDB can have?

Tags: mongodb

What is the maximum number of shards MongoDB can have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can handle hundreds without any problems. Maybe even thousands.

AFAIK, there's no hard-coded limit on that.

Comment: Sergio Tulentsev is correct, there is no hard-coded limit. There is a note on this in the Mongo Document on Sharding Limits: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Limits#ShardingLimits-ScaleLimits

Comment: @XiaoboGu "it says a sharded cluster need a replicated set" - it doesn't say that.