# Having large number of collections in MongoDB ( Need Schema Design suggestions )

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am considering MongoDB to hold metadata of images, recorded from 100 cameras, and the records will be kept for 30 days for each camera. If one camera gives 100,000 images in a day then i am going to save (**100 x 30 x 100000**) images (documents) at max in MongoDB. My web application will query this data as:

**Select a Camera > Select a Date > Select an Hour > Fetch all images in that hour.**

I plan to design schema with following three options, and need your expert opinion/suggestion for the best way out;

1) **Hour-wise Collections:** Create **72000 MongoDB Collections**, i.e. **1 Collection per Hour for each Camera** (100 cameras X 30 days X 24 hours) (using --nssize 500 command to exceed 24000 limit). I am afraid if MongoDB will allow me to create these much collections and secondly what are expected performance benefits and losses while reading and writing to these collection. Though, for reading per hour images looks tremendously easy with this schema, because i can fetch data in a single query to any Collection.

2) **Day-wise Collections:** Create **3000 MongoDB Collections**, i.e. **1 Collection per Day for each Camera** (100 cameras X 30 days). Though this is allowable and seems good number of collection but my concern is reading images from a particular hour inside particular day collection.

3) **Camera-wise Collections:** Create **100 MongoDB Collections**, i.e. **1 Collection for each Camera** (100 cameras/collections). Then saving snapshots with unique 'id' in format like (20141122061055000) that is a rephrasing of full date timestamp (2014-11-22 06:10:55.000).

I wish if ideally i could do (1), (2) or (3) but any other option is welcomed.

Please suggest about my selection for MongoDB as well, considering my case.

Regards.

Comment: Eventually I decided to go for option (3). Using such timestamped Id made it dramatically easy for me to searches with MongoDB Regex support. Also as a trick I saved the same timestamp value as two different data types (String and Long number). String timestamp helped simplifying searches with Regex and Long timestamp helped improving sorting as well as indexing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This continues from: [Pros and Cons of using MongoDB instead of MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190468/pros-and-cons-of-using-mongodb-instead-of-ms-sql-server/13191791#13191791).

I am unsure why you are trying to take the advise of using many collections.

Using many collections in this way in MongoDB is considered a bad idea (and you would have to increase ns size for this most likely after your index overhead), you should instead scale a single collection of common docs way out horizontally. It seems the other answerers agree.

I would use a single collection with a document structure maybe of (quick off the top of my head):

```
{
    _id: {},
    camera_id: ObjectId(),
    image: {},
    hour: ts_of_hour,
    day: ts_of_day
}
```

That way you got all the data you need to select images based on whatever denomination you want.

NB: Consider as well that MongoDBs lock is database level, not collection level. You won't gain anything useful here only making your querying harder and more complex and maybe making your data harder to maintain.

#### Edit

To answer some of your concerns:

NB: I have not designed your app and this is a late answer (late at night too) so basically this is me fleshing out basic concepts that immediately come to mind.

> 1 collection for each camera, i.e. 100 collections almost.

Again I don't really see the point, if you were to do this for optimisation reasons then you would do it as one camera per DB, but that is officially overkill. Honestly 30m records is nothing, I will resolve that concern right now. Whether you are talking about SQL or MongoDB a 30m record collection is normally considered small, minute even, in terms of the databases potential (with MS SQL saying they can store perabytes per table).

> 1. Select All images of between FromDate and ToDate 2

You can use the answer above to accomplish that using a BSON date field on your document.

> 2. Select Top(COUNT) images between FromDate and ToDate

You can just `count()`.

`top()` is not implemented in all DB systems so this is MS SQL specific here however in this particular query it does nothing useful since that query will always return one row.

You can aggregate this particular data to another collection. That is fine, so in another collection you would have a set of days:

```
{
     count: 3,
     day: (date|ts)
}
```

And then you can just some up over the days since `count()` can get slow on a large working set. So the aim of the collection to summarise your data to make your working set for queries more manageable.

So other collections are fine to use to hold "cache" of aggregation functions which would be slow, or of course to hold other entities within your app (like a relational DB would).

Basically, like in SQL, common schemas or documents get grouped in collections. So really I would design your app in SQL with only one table: `images` and maybe `camera` as well.

All others except for 5 have been covered loosely here so:

> 5. Select previous/next images from/to an Image with an ID

You can use the `_id` here like so:

```
db.images.find({_id: {$gt: last_id}}).limit(1)
```

And that should work pretty well.

As for the comment you posted here as well:

> Do you mean that in MongoDB, querying a collection with 30 documents is not different from querying a collection with 30,00,000 documents ?

Now that depends on how much you know about database design in general and how to scale database architecture. This is something that doesn't just apply to MongoDB but also to SQL. If set-up right SQL can easily query 30m records like 30.

What it all comes down to is sharding. As to whether it would be fast comes down to your indexes across those shards that the queries to run and their working set size (how much data is needed in RAM, is it in RAM?). By the looks of it a shard index over image_id (`ObjectId`) and date might give you what you want. However this will need more testing and since I believe you are a little new to scaling databases you should really do some searching on this subject via Google or something.

NB again: 30m documents might not need sharding so this could be just a case of making good indexes.

Hopefully this helps and I haven't gone round in circles here,

Comment: So, i am considering the idea of using less number of collections, e.g. 1 collection for each camera, i.e. 100 collections almost. Taking your great advice for schema design I really need more optimized version of it, considering following queries against single CameraId;

1. Select All images of between FromDate and ToDate
2. Select Top(COUNT) images between FromDate and ToDate
3. Select First Image for Any Hour of a Date
4. Select one Image with an ID (auto number - self generated)
5. Select previous/next images from/to an Image with an ID
6. Count total number of Images in an Hour

Comment: @theGeekster Ok added a bit of an edit.

Comment: Thanks for another great piece of advice :)
Currently i am using MS SQL, and have 1 table for 1 camera records (30,00,000). And querying this table against date field often takes longer and i have setup a custom cache between my web app and db. Cache query db only in case images for requested day for a camera are not already requested. The Cache behaves unpredictable, that's why i am considering a better/stable/robust solution.

Comment: @theGeekster Hmm if the cache behaves weirdly there might be some optimisations needed within your DB. It might be that you put all on one commodity server when in reality you needed a bigger one, or your app might have been doing queries that caused a huge result set (far more than you needed) and saturated your IO.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your problem with the collections. Photos are one single scheme, and they should be in a single collection.

Each photo gets a timestamp. The rest is done by [querying](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries). You can query documents per hour without a problem:

```
var begin_hour = new Date(date.year, date.month, date.day, hour);
var end_hour = new Date(date.year, date.month, date.day, hour + 1);

db.photos.find({taken: {$gte: begin_hour, $lt: end_hour}})
```

This selects the photos by the selected `hour`.

If that doesn't satisfy you, there's also [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce).

Comment: I am trying to categorize my images (documents) into different collections (days/hours). My intention to do this is derived from followings:
1. Querying a collection containing 1,00,000 documents might be better than one containing 30,00,000 documents

2. If i would be able to create Hour-wise collections (72000) then i may even save the DATE comparison in query and directly load that specific whole collection

This is how i am thinking, might be wrong. Need your suggestions on either more number of collections OR fewer collection with large number of documents inside (say 30,00,000 each).

Comment: @theGeekster You are missing the point of collections in Mongo. They are only to collect documents of the same structure. They are meant to contain a large number of documents. Normal DBs in Mongo only contain a dozen collections, and the entire database is made to support this. I advise you to look at [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), which follows your idea of collections a bit more than MongoDB does. MongoDB collections are comparable to SQL Tables, nothing else.

Comment: @theGeekster MongoDB is optimised for such numbers of documents in one collection. That's what [Indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes) are for. A mongoDB collection in production may contain billions of documents, clustered. Indexes made sure the query always runs optimally.

Comment: @theGeekster If I were you, I would store data in one collection at first. In my opinion, I think you just optimize too early.

Comment: Do you mean that in MongoDB, querying a collection with 30 documents is not different from querying a collection with 30,00,000 documents ?

Comment: Agree, this needs one collection. Any multi-collection approach for this makes no sense. @theGeekster Querying 30,000,000 entries in one collection is quicker than querying across 1,000,000 collections each with 30 entries, yes.